# How to stack probabilities based on conditions of previous result

Tags: probability, dice

I have three dice: 8 sided, 3 sided, and 4 sided.

I roll them in order 8, 3, 4.

I only roll the next one if the previous result is a '1'.

What is the probability of getting 1, then 1, then 1?

Is `p = (1/8)x(1/3)x(1/4)` correct?

Would there be a 1.04% chance of that result?

Is there a correct name or way to reference this type of probability where you only stack on an additional probability based on the outcome of the previous outcome?

I used "stack probabilities" out of naivety.

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Thanks @user3257842; I have added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_1$ be event that you have $1$ on the $8$-sided die, $A_2$ be event that you have $1$ on $3$-sided die and let $A_3$ be event that you have $1$ on $4$-sided die.
We will use [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability)) here (which is often called product rule):

$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \mathbb{P}(A_3 |A_2\cap A_1)\cdot\mathbb{P}(A_2|A_1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_1)$.

We assume that every die is fair so you have equal probability to get any one of its sides.

So $\mathbb{P}(A_1) = \frac{1}{8}$.

And if you had got $1$ on the first die then you have probability $\mathbb{P}(A_2|A_1) = \frac{1}{3}$ that you would have $1$ on the second die.

If you got $1$ on the first die and $1$ on the second die then $\mathbb{P}(A_3 |A_2\cap A_1) = \frac{1}{4}$ is the probability that you will get $1$ on the last die.

Stacking all together we get your answer:

$\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap A_3) = \mathbb{P}(A_3 |A_2\cap A_1)\cdot\mathbb{P}(A_2|A_1)\mathbb{P}(A_1) = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{96}$.

Comment: Thank you @perepelart I will look into the chain/product rule - I wasn't sure what to call it and just added confusion over what to call it to the question. This all makes sense.

Comment: @Craig you used this proposition intuitively in your solution. But anyway it can be rigorously proved for any $n$ just with using definition of the conditional probability and mathematical induction.